# Query issues in getting a predefined output

Tags: sql

Table:info
**

```
id table     parent_code   code
1  Furniture  0            xyz
2  Wood       xyz          kbc
3  bed        kbc          wxy
Output Table:
Name   Parent
Wood   Furniture
Bed    Wood
```

**

What I wrote:

```
select i.name, t.name from info as i,info as t where i.code=t.parent_code
```

Can U correct this code

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need the outpur using single query, as shown in the output table

Comment: [W3Schools - Sql Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is self-join.

Try the following

```
select i.name as name, t.name as parent 
from info as i 
join info as t on i.code=t.parent_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  
    I.name as name
    , p.name as parent 
from 
    info I 
inner join 
    info p 
on 
    i.parentcode=p.code
```